# How to hide a menu when an item is clicked or hide the menu when someone clicks away

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So i want to hide my bootstrap menu on the event when an item is clicked. This is my menu code

```
<div class="container visible-xs" id="top">
     <div class="header-bottom navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="top-nav">
          <span class="menu"><img src="images/pic copy.png" alt="toggle"> <a href="#">  BESSIT4REAL</a></span>
              <ul id="ul">
                  <li><a href="index.html#top">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#music">Music</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

              </ul>

          </div>
         <div class="social-icons">
             <ul class="social">
                 <li><a  href="#" ><i> </i> </a></li>
                 <li><a  href="#" ><i class="rss"></i></a></li>
                 <li><a  href="https://twitter.com/bessit_deejay" ><i class="twitter"></i></a></li>

             </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
     <br class="visible-xs">
</div>
```

and this is my javascript code

```
<script>
    $("span.menu").click(function(){
        $(".top-nav ul").slideToggle(500, function(){
            $("#ul li a").click(function() {
               $(".ul").hide(); 
            });
        });
        $('')
    });
</script>
```

Basically i need to hide the entire "`<ul>`" element when the `<li>` item is clicked,
Currently when someone click on home or about, the menu stays on the screen and does not disappear.

Comment: `$("span.menu").click(function(){
$(".top-nav ul").slideToggle(500);        
$('')
});
$("#ul li a").click(function(){
$("#ul").hide();
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following Jquery Code:

```
<script>
$(".top-nav li").click(function(){
    $(".top-nav ul").slideToggle(500, function(){
           $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(".ul").hide();
```

references all elements with a class of "ul"  You probably want (in your code example) the id referece

```
$("#ul").hide();
```

Or if you want all the `<ul>` elements then give them both the same class  (like "hideableUL") then you could go like:

```
$(".hideableUL").hide();
```

Comment: That seems to have worked but the menu seems to still be buggy, sometimes it stays on the screen or moves with it, I dont know if the js is buggy or badly written, any thoughts?

Comment: That all has to do with bootstrap.  I only know jquery.  sorry.

Comment: try to collapse the menu before hiding.

Comment: I tried to change a few things and it worked for me, the issue seems resolved

Answer (score 1):

you have an error.. your `ul` has an ID not a class, so you should us `'#'` in your jquery.

And to hide your ul you can use either `hide()` or `fadeOut(0)`..

```
$("#ul li a").click(function() {
     $("#ul").fadeOut(0); 
});
```

or

```
$("#ul li a").click(function() {
     $(this).fadeOut(0); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it helped.

```
$("span.menu").click(function(){
                            $(".top-nav #ul").slideToggle(500, function(){
                                $("#ul li a").click(function() {
                                   $(".top-nav #ul").hide(); 
                                });
                            });
                            $('')
                        });
```